# Custom activity based on HandleExternalEventActivity

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, roles

I'm using `HandleExternalEventActivity` with `Roles` property and I need to check if my **custom** `bool RoleProfile.IsDelegatee(string userName, string workflowName, string activityName, string eventName, string roleName)`  method finds a match. ("I'm on vacation; UserX should be able to approve 'task X' on my behalf, but not 'task Y'")

I tried to inherit `HandleExternalEventActivity` but `Execute` method was marked as sealed.

Do you have any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the HandleExternalEventActivity lets you do this, it's limited in what it will let you validate. However the ReceiveActivity has a OperationValidation event that lets you do whatever you want in code and set an IsValid property on the OperationValidationEventArgs to indicate if the call is allowed or not.

If you are not willing or able to go the WCF route the best option is to create a custom activity that reacts to queued messages. The HandleExternalEventActivity is only a very thin wrapper over the workflow queuing system and I nearly always advise people to go the custom activity route instead of the HandleExternalEventActivity route as it is far more flexible and often even easier to use.